# Difference between NaviagtionService.GoBack() and Application.Current.RootVisual

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Can anybody explain me , whats the difference this two

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

and

```
var rootFrame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
if (rootFrame != null)
rootFrame.GoBack();
```

Both of this will navigate to the previous page, but i want to know the difference between this two.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference, they call the same code internally.